# Istio DestinationRule consistentHash for sticky session not working

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, sticky-session

We have a service that runs on 3 to 5 pods that connect to a database. Every time the user enters the domain, and once logged in, shortly, we are forced to reload and go back to the login screen. It does not happen with 1 pod. Without multiple pods, it tries to go to another pod once after login and goes back to login screen.

We have a simple Gateway > VirtualService > DestinationRule setup for this application

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
name: our-gateway
spec:
selector:
istio: ingressapp
servers:
 - hosts:
  - app.com
port:
 name: http
 number: 80
 protocol: HTTP


apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
name: our-virtualservice
spec:
gateways:
- our-gateway
hosts:
- app.com
http:
-  match:
-  uri:
prefix: /
route:
- destination:
host: app 
port:
number: 8080

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
 name: destinationrule
spec:
 host: app.com
 trafficPolicy:
  loadBalancer:
   consistentHash:
    useSourceIp: true
  tls:
   mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

This stickiness does not work. I had also tried:

```
consistentHash:
  httpCookie:
   name: user
   ttl: 0s
```

httpCookie also did not work.

What is blocking it from working? Using DestinationRule still doesn't enable any stickiness and had no effect.

Comment: Please enable proxy protocol.  Following link has details. https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/show-source-ip/

Comment: you are saying the missing piece is to create proxy-protocol Envoy Filter?

Comment: not only envoy filter.  the policy needs to be created in LB and annotations to be added in ingress gateway etc.

Comment: For policy you can check cloud provider documentation and other details are in above link

Comment: when you say policy in the LB. What is an example of that because the article doesn't mention a word of policy. Also that more geared towards AWS when we have GCP

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/setting-up-tcp#additional_configuration_options
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#ip_addresses

Answer (score 1):

For session stickiness to reflect add ttl with some value. currently you are setting 0s, try with ttl: 500s